# Speeding Up Matrix Inversion

Tags: numpy, optimization, scipy, statistics

I need to run this code thousands of time, sequentially:

```
def update_posterior(y, x, prior_mu, prior_V, prior_a, prior_b):

    # Building blocks used to keep following calculation cleaner
    prior_cov_inverse = np.linalg.inv(prior_V)
    x_transpose = x.transpose()
    n = len(y)
    residuals = y - np.dot(x, prior_mu.transpose())

    # Calculation of posterior parameters
    V_posterior = np.linalg.inv((prior_cov_inverse + x_transpose * x))
    mu_posterior = (V_posterior * (prior_cov_inverse * prior_mu.transpose() + x_transpose * y)).transpose()
    a_posterior = prior_a + n/2
    b_posterior = np.asscalar(prior_b + (residuals.transpose() * np.linalg.inv((np.identity(n) + x * prior_V * x_transpose)) * residuals)/2)

    return mu_posterior, V_posterior, a_posterior, b_posterior
```

The way it works is that the output of the function is fed back into it, with `mu_posterior` becoming `prior_mu`, `V_posterior` becoming `prior_V`, `a_posterior` becoming `prior_a`, and `b_posterior` becoming `prior_b` for the next call. The y and x are different in each call.

This function is horrendously slow--it takes me about 8 seconds to run. This is because of the scale. I have ~5000 parameters, so `prior_mu` is (1, 5000), `prior_V` is (5000,5000) and symmetric `positive-definite`, and `prior_a`, and `prior_b` are scalars. y is a scalar, and x is (1, 5000).

Here is the time breakdown by line:

```
3.75s: prior_cov_inverse = np.linalg.inv(prior_V)
3.86s: V_posterior = np.linalg.inv((prior_cov_inverse + x_transpose * x))
0.13s: b_posterior = np.asscalar(prior_b + (residuals.transpose() * np.linalg.inv((np.identity(n) + x * prior_V * x_transpose)) * residuals)/2)
```

Any ideas how I can speed it up? I tried to use a Cholesky decomposition but it's even slower?! My guess is there is a more efficient way to implement Cholesky decomposition in Python.

```
prior_cov_inverse2 = np.linalg.inv(np.linalg.cholesky(prior_V))
prior_cov_inverse2 = np.dot(prior_cov_inverse2.transpose(), prior_cov_inverse2)
```

EDIT: Here are some sample data to illustrate the issue....

```
import numpy as np

prior_mu = np.asmatrix(np.full((1, 5040), 5))
prior_V = np.diagflat(np.asmatrix(np.full((1, 5040), 30))) #usually not diagonal, but always symmetric positive definitive
a = 2
b = 2
y = np.asmatrix([10])
x = np.asmatrix(np.concatenate(([1], np.zeros(5039))))

print(update_posterior(y, x, prior_mu, prior_V, a, b))
```

EDIT II:

I have been able to get this down from ~8s/run to ~1.4s/run by removing matrix inversions in favor of solves and also using the Sherman Morrison formula. Here is my current code. If anyone has any ideas on how to speed it up further, please share! :)

```
def update_posterior(y, x, prior_mu, prior_V, prior_a, prior_b, I):

    # Building blocks used to keep following calculation cleaner
    x_transpose = x.transpose()
    n = len(y)
    residuals = y - np.dot(x, prior_mu.transpose())

    # Calculation of posterior parameters
    # Below is equivalent to np.linalg.inv(prior_V_inverse + np.dot(x_transpose, x)) but significantly faster    
    V_posterior = prior_V - np.true_divide(np.linalg.multi_dot((prior_V, x_transpose, x, prior_V)), 1 + np.matmul(np.matmul(x, prior_V), x_transpose))

    # Below is equivalent to mu_posterior = np.dot(V_posterior, (np.matmul(prior_V_inverse, prior_mu.transpose()) + np.matmul(x_transpose, y))).transpose() but significantly faster
    mu_posterior = np.dot(V_posterior, np.linalg.solve(prior_V, prior_mu.transpose()) + np.matmul(x_transpose, y)).transpose()
    a_posterior = prior_a + n/2
    b_posterior = np.asscalar(prior_b + (np.matmul(np.matmul(residuals.transpose(), np.linalg.inv((np.identity(n) + np.matmul(np.matmul(x, prior_V), x_transpose)))), residuals))/2)

    return mu_posterior, V_posterior, a_posterior, b_posterior
```

Comment: Are you 100% positive that you really need to invert those matrices? [People generally try very hard not to.](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/)

Comment: Sure that `y` is a scalar? If so,  `n = len(y)` is slightly misleading. I guess it might be helpful to post sample data for y, x, prior_mu, prior_V, prior_a and prior_b. By the way, you could take a look at [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I am not 100% sure I need to invert them, but I am not sure how to restructure this so I do not have to invert them. My current implementation is the "textbook equation" version. y does not have to be scalar, but in practice I am putting in only one x,y pair into the model at a time.

Comment: @joni I added some sample data, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stability-wise, it's almost always better to write `solve(A, unit_matrix)` instead of `inv(A)`. That won't help with performance though.

Performance of linear algebra here is almost surely fixed by the underlying LAPACK library. Stock ATLAS is likely slowest, OpenBLAS or MKL are better, sometimes much better.

However, I'm pretty sure the main improvement here is indeed algorithmic. First, for PSD matrices Cholecky (cholesky/cho_solve) should be better. Second, you seem to be doing a rank-one update (`x.T @x`), and *that* can typically be implemented in `N**2` operations via some variant of the Shermann-Morrison formula, instead of `N**3` for direct inversion.

Comment: I got it down to 1.3s with your advice! It was faster not to use Cholesky though. Do you have any other tips on how to make this go faster? Still quite slow given the number of repeats I need.